# What stickers have special "scratched" patterns?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

[image]

As seen here, from Reddit, if the Welcome to the Clutch sticker is scratched off enough, it reads "Welcome to Hell" followed with 4 skulls scratched into the bottom.

Are there any other stickers that do a similar thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Welcome to the Clutch
- Queen of Pain
- T-Rekt